# Retrieving the Return Value of a Stackless Python Tasklet Bound Function?

Tags: python, stackless, python-stackless

Stackless Experts,

I have managed to create tasklets under Stackless Python (both from the Stackless and the C side).

It seems to me that in order to create a tasklet in Stackless, you bind an arbitrary Python callable (function) to the tasklet (as well as the required parameters), so the bound callable would be run as a tasklet. However, an arbitrary callable might actually have a return value that's important to the caller. But I have yet to see a way to retrieve the return value of the bound callable running as a tasklet.

On the pure Stackless Python side, I do see a usage idiom called Micromanaging, which wraps the original function with a managing function, which in turn *could* capture the return value of the original function and save it somewhere for use in some other context.

Unfortunately, my special use case involves creating a tasklet from the C (C++) side, binding to a (potentially blocking) Python callable which has an important return value to be used later. It seems that writing such a Micromanaging function on the C side is not very feasible, since I haven't found a way to turn a C function into a PyObject callable dynamically (not involving module table initialization, etc.), and using static stateless C function (I would assume the prototype has to be PyObject* (PyObject*, PyObject*)) is generally a bad idea under C++ world anyways.

The Stackless C API also seems not containing a proper function to retrieve the return value of a tasklet. Is it the only option that I have to write above mentioned Micromanaging function (*could* be stateful) in Python, and provide a way to retrieve the return value saved somewhere (in a stateful fashion, i.e. not using global variables)? Or there could be other options I could possibly explore?

Thank you very much,

Lin

P.S. I understand that on the C and operating system level programming, the return value of a thread function is only meaningful for exit code, and thread functions would have a strict function prototype, i.e. C functions have to abide by some strict rules to become runnable as/by a thread. And now we are talking about Python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Stackless.com:

"... But I have yet to see a way to retrieve the return value  of the bound callable running as a tasklet. ..."

I do not know that there is one.

"...important return value to be used later. It seems that writing such a  Micromanaging function on the C side is not very feasible, since I  haven't ..."

The simplest way to do this would be to define the wrapping Python function code in C as a string, and to compile it into a function object that you can run as a tasklet.  An example Python function follows, the C part I leave to you.

e.g.

```
  def RunFunctionAndGetResult(chan, func, *args, **kwargs):
      chan.send(func(*args, **kwargs))
```

Cheers,

Richard.

Comment: If you have the leisure to define the above Python function in one of your Python modules, then you don't have to compile the above function in the format of a C string; on the C side, you can just get the reference to that function and wrap it to a tasklet!